# Chow rings for analytic spaces

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Is there any meaningful theory of Chow rings for complex analytic spaces?

It seems to me that all definitions of cycles and cycles rationally (meromorphically) equivalent to zero go through. However, there is no mention of the concept of such an "analytical" version anywhere.

Is it because these definitions yield something trivial?